# Tor crashes GNOME Shell

Tags: debian, proxy

I've a fairly vanilla Debian with GNOME Shell install configured to use a system Tor daemon as a SOCKS proxy in Settings -> Network -> Network proxy.

If I kill the Tor process, then the system hangs.  This happens if tor is killed directly or using `systemd`.  It's just some part of GNOME Shell that crashes, as the system does not hang if I kill tor from a virtual concole.

Any thoughts on what processes need to die when the tor process dies to prevent this?

Comment: Before killing Tor, have a look at the output of `systemctl list-dependencies`. This will give a dependency tree for those processes know to `systemd`. Find Tor, and look for any child branches, which will be the processes depending on Tor. (It's possible this won't help as it'll likely be an issue with another process not managed by `systemd`. You'd also hope `systemd` could handle processes it knows about dying. Worth checking as a first step though.)

Comment: There are no dependencies listed for tor.service.  It's part some of GNOME Shell that cannot handle it's socks proxy dying, not anything managed by systemd.

Comment: Okay, next idea - check which processes are using the proxy. Something like `netstat` might work for this (e.g. as described in this answer: http://serverfault.com/a/192920/223849).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not an issue about Tor, but rather a bug in GNOME Shell

Comment: Appears fixed now anyways, but generally these sorts of questions should stay around for people who need to debug how badly behaved applications interact with SOCKS proxies like Tor.  And Richard's comments were useful.